# error while adding repo for kde plasma 5 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kde

I was trying to install KDE plasma 5 in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
when i am trying to add

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:neon/kf5
```

i am getting this error

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:neon/kf5'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I was following the tutorial [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492599/how-to-install-and-test-kde-plasma-5-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: What is your question? Why do you think "ppa:neon/kf5" is a valid PPA? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/548591/edit) and add the information.

Comment: Sorry about that, i have edited and added

Comment: Don't be sorry, But, well. You still didn't ask a question... what is your question?

Comment: It's not duplicate. The ppa:neon/kf5 seems down. I was using and getting updates but suddenly stopped, saying the address doesn't exist.

Comment: I got a response from kubuntu team Valorie, on the irc. She said this ppa has been discontinued and Plasma 5 will not be available to 14.04 anymore. The only way is to upgrade to 14.10 (and add the next PPA) or download Plasma5 iso for testing.

The following link she answers another user:
https://plus.google.com/+ThiagoAderaldo/posts/PJpRazMb8tF