# KDE Plasma Desktop 5 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kde

I heard that the K Desktop Environment Plasma Desktop 5 is out. I want to try it out on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer (not Kubuntu).  I am aware that Project Neon no longer exists. Can anyone tell me a PPA that still works?

EDIT: This is actually a dupicate question of [How To Install And Test KDE Plasma 5 On Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492599/how-to-install-and-test-kde-plasma-5-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Plasma 5 in Kubuntu 14.04 you need to add the Project Neon KDE Frameworks 5 PPA on your system:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/kf5
```

Update the repository

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install kde plasma 5 package with dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install project-neon5-session project-neon5-utils project-neon5-konsole project-neon5-breeze project-neon5-plasma-workspace-wallpapers
```

Comment: That PPA is deprecated.