# Install Kde Plasma 5 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kde

i'm trying to install kde5 on ubuntu 14.04 but after update system and add some PPA, packages dont find in repository.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-plasma5-desktop

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kubuntu-plasma5-desktop
```

or this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/kf5
Cannot add PPA: 'No JSON object could be decoded'.
```

or try this way:

```
sudo apt-get install project-neon5-session project-neon5-utils                              

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 project-neon5-session : Depends: project-neon5-plasma-framework but it is not installable
                         Depends: project-neon5-kde-workspace but it is not installable
                         Depends: project-neon5-kde-runtime but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how to add correct repository and resolve this problem

Comment: take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/492599/how-to-install-and-test-kde-plasma-5-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Actually, you can no longer install Plasma 5 on Trusty or Utopic. If you want Plasma 5 along with Frameworks 5 and Applications 14.10/15.04, you need Vivid.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda yes. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: @saiarcot895 whats Vivid sir?

Comment: Vivid is Ubuntu 15.04. Utopic is Ubuntu 14.10. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) for the full list of code names.