# How to upgrade to KDE Plasma 5 on Ubuntu 14.04.3?

Tags: kde

I've followed many tutorial but my KDE is still version 4.12.2....

I've tested

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but nothing works :(

In some websites I've found this instruction

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/kf5
```

but they dont work either!
How to do it in Ubuntu 14.04.3?

I really like the plasma 5 desktop....

Any help would be much appreciated....

> **EDIT:** It's not possible with 14.04 LTS

Comment: what is output of `kate --version`

Comment: Qt: 4.8.6   KDE Development Platform: 4.14.2   Kate: 3.14.2

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/417/how-do-i-install-kde/680000#680000) and let me know whether it solved or not =)

Comment: Please check this answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/496591/181359

Answer (score 4):

Run the following commands in terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop plasma-workspace plasma-workspace-wallpapers
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next-backports'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

it shows :/

Comment: Just now edited @jamius,previous PPA for 14.10

Comment: trying now :D
wait

Comment: jamius19@blackout19:~$ sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop plasma-workspace plasma-workspace-wallpapers

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package plasma-workspace
E: Unable to locate package plasma-workspace-wallpapers


shows this

Comment: getting the same error as @jamius19 . Is there a way to get KDE 5 on 14.04.3?.. :-(

Comment: I don't think there is any plasma 5 package in this backport ppa for 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend just updating Ubuntu itself. You just need to make a boot disk of the latest version of Ubuntu, and select "Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.10"(or a similar option). Just follow the instructions. Then type `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` at a terminal when you've booted in! Note that you will have to reinstall your programs and change your settings again.

Comment: -1 because this answer ignores the question; It clearly says "KDE Plasma 5 on Ubuntu 14.04", so upgrading to 15.10 means "KDE Plasma 5 in Ubuntu 15.10" and *not* 14.04 anymore.