# Ended up having kde 4.x (plasma 4) instead of Plasma 5.4 from Ubuntun 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kde, desktop-environments, plasma

I was using Unity on Ubuntu 14.04 and was giving me trouble after going dual monitors, so decided to give KDE a try. So I installed KDE by following the commands below found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492599/how-to-install-and-test-kde-plasma-5-on-ubuntu-14-04/623488#623488) hoping that I'll get Plasma 5.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
```

I really like KDE but I have ended up with KDE Plasma 4.x as the --version says below:

```
$ plasma-desktop -version
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.2
Plasma Desktop Shell: 4.11.11
```

And also here's how IKnfocenter looks:
[image]

How do I get Plasma 5.4 (NOT 5.3 as it's unstable from what I read)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Ubuntu 14.04, you got the repository from Kubuntu 14.04 which doesn't have Plasma 5 yet.

Comment: how do I install plasma 5 then? is it not possible from 14.04?

Comment: No, it's not possible from 14.04. Only from 15.04 and above. 

Here https://community.kde.org/Plasma/LiveImages you can download some Live Images of distributions that ship with Plasma 5.

Comment: sorry but does that mean I need to have Kubuntu installed to try Plasma 5? (what i want is to install only the DE Plasma 5 with Ubuntu )

Comment: So upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 (Plasma 5.2.2) or 15.10 (Plasma 5.4.2) and repeat the process you made, although not recommend to mix two desktop environments in a single distro.